# how to decode sniffed packet using scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to get data of a packet sniffed using scapy python.
I tried `pkt['TCP'].payload.decode('utf-8')`  but it fails saying `AttributeError: decode`

Code:

```
if iface:
    sniff(prn=process_packet, iface=iface, store=False)
else:
    sniff(prn=process_packet, store=False)

def process_packet(packet):
     if(packet.haslayer('TCP')):
         print(packet['TCP'].payload.decode('utf-8'))
         # I also Tried
         print(str(packet['TCP'].payload))
```

The second print, only decodes parts of the payload and not all of it.

Can someone help on how can I properly pull packet data and decode it to string?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you're starting with (maybe run your code in scapy with output) and the desired end data state? What parts is the 2nd print not printing? (i.e. provide output).